# I am trying to store my media files in google drive. The application is not showing any error other than images are not showing on my web page

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models

This is my setting.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
...
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'jobs',
'gdstorage',

]
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static')
GOOGLE_DRIVE_STORAGE_JSON_KEY_FILE = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'Api_key.json')
GOOGLE_DRIVE_STORAGE_MEDIA_ROOT = '/media/'
GOOGLE_DRIVE_STORAGE_SERVICE_EMAIL = 'myaccount.iam.gserviceaccount.com'
GOOGLE_DRIVE_STORAGE_KEY = '555e8bc_My_Storage_Key_aa4375f'
```

This is my models.py:

```
from gdstorage.storage import GoogleDriveStorage

# Define Google Drive Storage
gd_storage = GoogleDriveStorage()

...

image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images', storage=gd_storage)
```

I am trying to show my media files on my home page but the images are not loading. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you see the images in your Google Drive account? If so, perhaps the file path will give you some hits about what's going on.

Comment: Thank you for ur reply. How can i see the files in my drive as I am not storing these files in my personal google drive?

Answer (score 0):

In your models.py: add permissions

```
from gdstorage.storage import GoogleDriveStorage, GoogleDrivePermissionType, GoogleDrivePermissionRole, GoogleDriveFilePermission

permission =  GoogleDriveFilePermission(
   GoogleDrivePermissionRole.READER,
   GoogleDrivePermissionType.USER,
   "example1@gmail.com",
)

gd_storage = GoogleDriveStorage(permissions=(permission, ))
```

Or you may follow [Documentation](https://medium.com/@mohammedabuiriban/how-to-use-google-cloud-storage-with-django-application-ff698f5a740f) to use a bucket to make the media publicly available